# how to Iterate through data and pass them into a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already created a menu button which display some default value, shows below.[image]

And I have a table which have the data I need,

```
return (
                        <UitkTableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <UitkTableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</UitkTableCell>
                            })}

                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                if(cell.column.Header == "Notes"){
                                    console.log(cell)//print result shows below

                                    return  <div style={{margin:'10px 0px 0px 0px'}}>
                                        <NotesSelection />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            })}

                        </UitkTableRow>
                    )
```

I want to put the value, "DELETE COMMENT 1" in my menu list, how can I do this?
[image]

I tried something like this, loop through the cell, but got error "cell.map" is not a function

```
{cell.map(c => {
                                                return (
                                                    <div>display</div>
                                                )
                                            })}
```

Edit:

```
const {value} = cell
                                    {
                                        value.map(c => {
                                            return  <div>
                                                <NotesSelection />
                                            </div>
                                        })
                                    }
```

```
interface NotesSelectionProps {
  selectNotes(note:string): string;
}

class NotesSelection extends React.Component<NotesSelectionProps, { show: boolean, noteS: string, value: string }> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      noteS: "",
      value: "",
    };
    note = notes.notes[0].name
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e: any) {
    const previousState = this.state['show'];
    this.setState({
      show: !previousState,
      noteS: note,
      value: "",
    });
    arrowState = previousState ? " ˅" : " ˄"
  }

  onMenuItemClick(name: string) {
    note = name
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      noteS: note,
      value: "",
    });

    this.props.selectNotes(note)
    arrowState = " ˅"
    return;
  }


  render() {
    var name = this.props
    var noes: any = []
    notes.notes.forEach(element => {
      var note = {
        className: 'uitk-list-item',
        label: element.name,
        onClick:  () => this.onMenuItemClick(element.name),
        typeAnchor: true,
        target: "_blank"
      }
      noes.push(note)
    });

    noes.push(value)
    var buttonStyle = {
      padding:'5px',
      width:'170px',
      display:'flex',
      justifyContent:'space-between',
      background:'white',
      borderRadius: "10px",
      border:'1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
      fontSize: '14px',
      boxShadow: '0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%)'
    };

    return (
        <><div>

          <UitkMenu
              id="show10"
              isOpen={this.state.show}
              onTriggerClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            <UitkMenuTrigger >
              <button style={buttonStyle}>
                <div className="notes">
                  {note}
                </div>
                <div className="arrowState">
                  {arrowState}
                </div>
              </button>
            </UitkMenuTrigger>
            <UitkMenuContainer position={PositionType.LEFT} width={200}>
              <UitkMenuList items={noes} />
            </UitkMenuContainer>

          </UitkMenu>
        </div>
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: map method is used on an array and not on an object. So, maybe you can destructure the `cell` object `const {value} = cell` so that "DELETE COMMENT 1" is stored in the `value` variable, and then use that variable to display what you need.

Comment: Which is your menu list component?

Comment: @alonealgorithm I edited my code, still got the error "value.map is not a function"

Comment: @Prana is NotesSelection, do I need put that class here?

Comment: @John yeah, You need to modify that component. Isn't it? (menu list)

Comment: @Prana, I paste my component here, could you take alook?

Comment: @John I believe there's been some confusion. You don't want to use `value.map`. `value` holds the value of "DELETE COMMENT 1" which is not an array that you can use the map() method on. You said you needed "DELETE COMMENT 1" to be displayed. You now have access to the value in the `value` variable. Can you somehow use that variable in the code you return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to modify the menu list (NotesSelection) pass the value to that component and render it there.

NotesSelection component

```
interface NotesSelectionProps {
  selectNotes(note:string): string;
}

class NotesSelection extends React.Component<NotesSelectionProps, { show: boolean, noteS: string, value: string }> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      noteS: ""
    };
    note = notes.notes[0].name
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e: any) {
    const previousState = this.state['show'];
    this.setState({
      show: !previousState,
      noteS: note
    });
    arrowState = previousState ? " ˅" : " ˄"
  }

  onMenuItemClick(name: string) {
    note = name
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      noteS: note
    });

    this.props.selectNotes(note)
    arrowState = " ˅"
    return;
  }


  render() {
    var name = this.props
    var noes: any = []
    notes.notes.forEach(element => {
      var note = {
        className: 'uitk-list-item',
        label: element.name,
        onClick:  () => this.onMenuItemClick(element.name),
        typeAnchor: true,
        target: "_blank"
      }
      noes.push(note)
    });

    noes.push(value)

    var buttonStyle = {
      padding:'5px',
      width:'170px',
      display:'flex',
      justifyContent:'space-between',
      background:'white',
      borderRadius: "10px",
      border:'1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
      fontSize: '14px',
      boxShadow: '0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%)'
    };

    return (
        <><div>

          <UitkMenu
              id="show10"
              isOpen={this.state.show}
              onTriggerClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            <UitkMenuTrigger >
              <button style={buttonStyle}>
                <div className="notes">
                  {note}
                </div>
                <div className="arrowState">
                  {arrowState}
                </div>
              </button>
            </UitkMenuTrigger>
            <UitkMenuContainer position={PositionType.LEFT} width={200}>
              <UitkMenuList items={noes} />
            </UitkMenuContainer>

          </UitkMenu>
        </div>
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Table component

```
return (
                        <UitkTableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <UitkTableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</UitkTableCell>
                            })}

                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                if(cell.column.Header == "Notes"){
                                    console.log(cell)//print result shows below

                                    return  <div style={{margin:'10px 0px 0px 0px'}}>
                                        <NotesSelection value={cell.value} />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            })}

                        </UitkTableRow>
                    )
```

Comment: In the NotesSelection component,     noes.push(value), where can I pass the value in ?

Comment: Via NotesSelection component prop.

Comment: I edited the code above, but got error, "cannot find name value", could you take a look?

Comment: oh, i fix it, but using this.state.value it works, but I still get the default value in menu, didn't get the value I expected

Comment: What do you mean by default value and what do you expect?